# Question about customizing spring security 2.0.4

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi all I have the following requirement: The user will login to the system using olny his/her password and redirected to different pages depending his/her role (roles are DENTIST,DOCTOR,PHARMASIST).Are there any resources on how to use spring sequirity with  one-field login form and multiple default-target-urls? Any help would be really appriciated because googling the subject wasn't very useful... Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

What about using this approach:

Create a controller with mapping "/login-successful" and redirect successful logins to it. In this controller you identify the role of the user and then redirect him/her to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`determineTargetURL()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.html#determineTargetUrl%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)